# Terraform v0.11 efs access permission denied

Tags: terraform, amazon-efs, terraform0.11

just want to ask if this has been a known issue on Terraform v0.11, I'm trying to mount efs to lambda however it seems being blocked on the part of querying the efs access point.

```
data.aws_efs_access_point.pogi: data.aws_efs_access_point.pogi: Error reading EFS access point : AccessDeniedException: 
status code: 403, request id: 123k23s-1434-4421-as4ds-asd021390asdjj
```

my tf code below:

```
data "aws_efs_access_point" "pogi" {
    access_point_id = "fsap-p0gigwap0h"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "pogi_function" {
    function_name = "pogi-na-gwapo-pa"
  
    ...
  
  
    file_system_config {
      arn = "${data.aws_efs_access_point.pogi.arn}"
  
      local_mount_path = "/mnt/pogi-mo"
    }
  
}
```

NOTE: My tf code above is working when data source part is commented and arn value is hard coded

I'm using this IAM Role to deploy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt143441432",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:ListAliases",
                "lambda:TagResource",
                "lambda:UntagResource",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567898765:function:pogi-*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt143441432",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:Describe*",
                "elasticfilesystem:List*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-east-1:1234567898765:file-system/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are referencing the wrong ARN: `data.aws_efs_access_point.access.arn` and the name of the resource is `pogi`, i.e., you should reference `data.aws_efs_access_point.pogi.arn`.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE sorry  its a wrong substitution, I made a correction on my post.

Comment: I think you are missing some permissions for this to work. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-filesystem.html#configuration-filesystem-permissions and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-permissions.